# are android 10 adb commands gimp'd?

Tags: adb

`adb shell settings put secure sysui_nav_bar "\"key(82:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/menu.png),key(84:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/kb.png),back;home;recent;menu_ime;key(120:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/screenshot.png)\""`

what the heck is wrong with this adb command!?

i get tons of errors! on my Mac Mini Server 2012 via Bootcamp via Windows 10 Pro

for a moto g stylus 2043-4! May 12th 2020. Android Debug Bridge
30.0.1 installed via powershell via chocolatey.org

````
82:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/menu.png : The term '82:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/menu.png' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:52
+ ... sui_nav_bar "\"key(82:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/menu.png),key(84 ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (82:file:///stor.../0/zzz/menu.png:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

home : The term 'home' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:147
+ ... .png),key(84:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/kb.png),back;home;recent; ...
+                                                              ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (home:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

recent : The term 'recent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:152
+ ... ey(84:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/kb.png),back;home;recent;menu_im ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (recent:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

menu_ime : The term 'menu_ime' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:159
+ ... e:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/kb.png),back;home;recent;menu_ime;key(120 ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (menu_ime:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

120:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/screenshot.png : The term '120:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/screenshot.png' is
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:172
+ ... nt;menu_ime;key(120:file:///storage/emulated/0/zzz/screenshot.png)\""
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (120:file:///sto.../screenshot.png:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException```
````

Comment: Where did you get the command from? Shells differ often a bit, especially when it comes to escaping and quoting. I don't think may people already use Powershell. The common shell on Windows is cmd.exe.

Comment: i found bits of it online and built this command myself... clever noob i am huh? i used powershell only to install adb into my system. i dunno if cmd.exe is any better. but i used both to test my little command... no dice!

Comment: Please mention the source link for this command. It might not even work on an unrooted device or this specific model.

Comment: hmm... there is no one link. this custom command was built by piecing together tuts from various websites including here... it would be too tedious to re-find all of them!

Comment: it also worked flawlessly on a unrooted Moto G5 Plus XT1687

Comment: Probably related: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-change-your-nav-bar-icons-or-re-arrange-the-buttons-without-root/

Comment: you call a device and android version depending framework settings.jar which is not even available on all devices (samsung) just because it worked on Moto G5 this doesn't mean it's working. why don't you read the error messages? it says clearly the term 82:file, 120:file is not recognized... and so on

Comment: Why to to use the most complicated way and try t execute an shell command through adb from Windows? Just execute `adb shell` first and then on the adb shell `settings put secure ...` this way should cause much less trouble regarding the quotes.

Comment: Hmm... ```adb shell``` by itself? first? i never saw this before.

Comment: hmm... it seems to take with no errors, but i believe i need root via the ```su``` command first...

Answer (score 2):

To answer the headline question, no, Android 10 does not have "gimped" ADB commands, assuming you mean "restricted" or "crippled".

If you wrote this script, you're in the best position to debug it. If you put it together from several sources, some of which may have been for Windows and some for UNIX, you may well have the use and escaping of quote characters mixed up. Windows-style and UNIX-style command lines have *different* handling of quotes.

The best advice is normal for debugging: cut down the problem as much as possible and find ways to do its component parts before you try to put the whole thing together. Writing a complicated command may be good for your ego, but that does not impress computers ***at all***.